# VERITAS: VxVM vxvol ERROR V-5-1-1654 keyword clean not recognized for init operation

Tags: solaris, lvm

I have installed the Veritas Volume Manager on Solaris 10. And I am trying to create volumes from the vmdisks. I have created the vmdisks and created the disk group with 2 vm disks. I have created almost 3 sub disks (with same length) in each of the vm disk after the creation of the disk group. I have created the 3 plexes from the 6 sub disks and I created a logical volume using the 3 plexes with the below command.

```
# vxmake -g testgrp -Uraid5 vol testvol1 plex=testplex,testplex-2,testplex-3

But when I run the below command, I could see the plex and volumes as disabled.

# vxprint -hg testgrp
```

And I tried to run the below command before starting the volumes as the volume is empty.

```
# vxvol -g testgrp init clean testvol1
```

But at this point, I am getting the error as "VxVM vxvol ERROR V-5-1-1654 keyword clean not recognized for init operation".

Could anyone please help me in solving this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If raid5 is the type of volume you want to create I think you can use following command:

```
vxassist -g testgrp make testvol1 layout=raid5 disk1,disk2,disk3,...
```

It will take care to create the appropriate plex(es) and subdisks on the specified disks in the given diskgroup